# mapkit внутри NestedScrollView

Tags: android, nested-scrollview, mapkit

всем привет. проблема работы с mapkit, который лежит внутри NestedScrollView. жесты зума, перемещения по карте конфликтуют с родителем. как это победить? кто знает?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже надо реализовать 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild

И завернуть в него мапкит. Обычные списки в списках работают благодяря тому, что реализуют этот интерфейс.